Creating PresignedRequest using AWS SDK - Issue with us-east-1 region. Removed region from url
I am creating PresignedRequest using AWS SDK in php.
I have Url like :
https://test.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hmtest/img/44 46.pdf

after presigned I am getting:
https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/hmtest/img/44 46.pdf?**************************

Can anyone has idea  and this happen to specific us-east-1 region only?
Is there any way so that I can pass region manually in PresignedRequest creation call? Or any other way to handle it?

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use the URL given? It should work just the same. If you take the 'signature' part after the ? and attach it to the first URL, does it work?

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use the URL given?

No But i am not able to identify reason why it happen with us-east-1 only.


us-east-1 is the 'original' AWS region and it has some legacy. Back then, there was only one region so the URL didn't need to indicate a region name. That's why s3.amazonaws.com points to us-east-1. When more regions were added, the naming standard became s3.<region>.amazonaws.com. Both methods will work.

Legacy of S3 and AWS regional services. PS it's probably not ideal to name files like 44 46.pdf (with whitespace).

@jarmod Thanks for your reply. 44 46.pdf is just  random name added to hide original name
